# Issue with mysql-workbench 6.3.6 on Centos 7.2

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have recently installed mysql workbench (6.3.6) on CentOS (7.2) but i cannot create any tables.

The problem is that **i cannot add columns to tables**. Did anyone else face the same problem? Do i have to change settings and/or download additional software to solve this ?

Note: I have also tried to install the previous mysql workbench version but the problem is still there.

Can you recommend a stable working version of mysql workbench which i can install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am experiencing the same problem since I have updated from Centos (7.1 Build 1503) to CentOS(7.2 Build 1511).

Unless you have a reason to stick to CentOS 7.2 I suggest to revert back to CentOS 7.1. With that I am able to run Workbench (6.3.4) without problems.

In the meanwhile I came across the following bug report, which is exactly describing what I am experiencing.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79495

The new release of MySQL Worbench has solved the problem. Tested on a fresh installation of CentOS 7.2 running on Workbench.

Comment: Sorry for that. I ve just edited my answer to be, hopefully, of some help.